# Exporting data to excel sheet in an angular application

Tags: angular

There are external npm packages to export data into an excel sheet, however is there any inbuilt package on angular to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use xlsx  npm module. See [this](https://jsonworld.com/demo/how-to-export-data-to-excel-file-in-angular-application) sample application.

Comment: BTW, I would suggest you to use backend application for this as, this will resume more resources in client browser and may cause performance problems with large datasets.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this package,

`npm i xlsx`

For more info -  https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx